# CalendarEvent in CalendarApp... Manual Delete = Still Accessible Through Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I have several hundred events on the calendar, all created by Apps Script. I store their IDs in ScriptDB, and have a UI to manage them.

When I delete events ***manually*** (through the Google Calendar interface) off of my calendar, they disappear into oblivion, or so I thought. As it turns out, when I load my UI that manages them and I go and try to retrieve the event by:

`calendar.getEventSeriesById(eventID)`,

**I can access the events normally as if the event were still on the calendar**. The only thing that I *can't* seem to do, is *delete the event*. This honestly doesn't make any sense to me, but I'll give my two cents to see if you guys can come up with a reason as to why this might be happening. Here's the run-down of my use case:

1. Create an event through GAS (not manually).

   - Event is now on the calendar, event ID is stored in ScriptDB
2. Load UI - now we can change the date, start time, end time, location, description, etc. of the event, or we can delete it

   - No problems here, everything functions *normally and as expected*, even when the event is marked for deletion
3. Someone comes along and sees an event on the calendar and says *Oh, let's just go ahead and delete that shall we?*

   - This is where problems come in, because it's **impossible** (I'm almost certain) to detect that an event was deleted *manually* and subsequently set the eventID in ScriptDB to `null`.
4. Some time later... load up the UI... *woah*, getting event tags for a deleted event still works? *What*?

   ```
   [13-12-18 16:48:17:941 EST] This is an event that was manually deleted: CalendarEventSeries
   [13-12-18 16:48:17:943 EST] This is the location of the manually-deleted event: C/A
   ```
5. So now we can access the event, can we make any changes? *Spoiler: the answer is '**yes**':*

   - If I change the date, start time, end time, or location:

[image]

I get the following in my Logger (some important messages):

```
[13-12-18 19:34:12:208 EST] EVENT DATE/TIME CHANGED?: true
[13-12-18 19:34:12:534 EST] Manual change was made to the calendar event. Getting event by ID now...
[13-12-18 19:34:12:980 EST] Event to update (by ID): CalendarEventSeries
```

- This event was deleted, but apparently we can still make changes to it...

---

So I tried to catch the situation where the calendar event was deleted, but since after fetching by ID (or time interval for that matter), the return is a `CalendarEventSeries` when in actuality, ***the expected result*** is `null` or `0` or some other **falsey-value**.

Because I know that *I'm* the person who deleted the event, I thought *oh well, I'll just mark it for deletion in my UI!* Guess what: **fail**:
  - I tried to call `calEvent.deleteEventSeries();`, but I received the following error:

[image]

**So**: My only option was to surround the `calEvent.deleteEventSeries();` with a `try-catch-finally` block, which I suppose is a good enough solution. However, I am wondering why manually deleting off of the calendar still allows us access through GAS? The reverse holds to expectations: if I delete an event through GAS, it **does** actually delete it from the calendar. But deleting from the calendar manually does not remove access to the event by Apps Script.

**Finally the question(s)**: Is this *really* the intended behavior of `CalendarApp` and Apps Script? Or is this *unexpected or undefined* behavior? Are there any workarounds other than surrounding `deleteEventSeries()` in a `try-catch` block?

**EDIT**: According to the [original issue on the issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2480), even if you delete the event through Apps Script, then try and access it using the same `iCalId`, it still returns the event. So I guess it's not just manual deletion, it's deleting in general. I didn't notice this because when I delete the event, I erase the ID from ScriptDb. Something to look out for!

Comment: Hi Chris, this is a pretty well written question ! just a detail : when you manually delete the event do you get the same "answer" as the one we get for event series ? something like "only this one, all event of the serie ?"  or does it behave like a normal event (not part of an event serie ? And also : are you using recurrence on these script created events ?

Comment: Serge, the error occurs for both `CalendarEvent` and `CalendarEventSeries` objects, at least in the context of *how they were created/modified*. For example, if I can't get the event by time interval (through `getEvents(startTime, endTime)`), which would return a `CalendarEvent[]` -> which gives me a `CalendarEvent`, then I use `getEventSeriesById(eventID)` which gives me a CalendarEventSeries. When created, all events are `CalendarEvent`, *none* have recurrence. I only set a recurrence when I can't get the event by time interval (which would allow me to use `CalendarEvent.setTime()/endtime()`

Comment: That being said, whether or not an event actually *has* a recurrence when I try to delete it is arbitrary - they both throw the same error as shown in my question. However, my version of *recurrence* is actually just a workaround to set a new start and end time if an event was **forced** to be fetched by ID (if it couldn't be found by time interval). I never actually create a recurrence rule that has a yearly/monthly/daily recurrence, so in the case of *multiple events for one ID (a series)*, I actually don't know what the behavior is.

Comment: And sorry for yet another comment, but I'm running out of space! I imagine the the behavior for an **actual** series with *multiple events* would be the same, because the *original event* would be the one that is deleted, thus (theoretically) throwing errors for at least one, if not all, events in the series. I hope that makes sense... I don't really have time to test this particular case, but I can imagine that since the behind-the-scenes implementation is just `CalendarEventSeries`, that the same error message would arise no matter how many events are actually in the series.

Comment: Thanks Chris, now it's clear. I'm surprised I never noticed that issue since I've spend many many hours playing with calendars :-)  but it was rarely in this direction indeed. Anyway our friend Mogsdad has found what matters, as usual ^^.I just saw you comment 2, you're right, that one I knew!  But IMO this is not an issue, just a logical behavior

Comment: Yeah, he always does! Hopefully this will be the question that pops up when people have similar issues, because the issue tracker is **never** my first stop when I run into problems like these... although maybe it should be!

Comment: About your edit:  when you delete an event by script it does not appear in the calendar UI anymore so it does actually delete the event. I never tried to get a deleted event by ID from a script but I'll try and let you know.

Comment: I do confirm that events deleted by script *are* deleted but re-reading my script I understand now why I never noticed that issue, I get events from calendar and then compare with IDs on my SS and if I find a match I delete in a try/catch because I have often many events with the same ID (event with recurrences) so the error never pops up of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad news, Chris. This has been a known issue for a long time. [Issue 2480](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2480) was triaged and replicated in an internal bug report by the GAS team 9 months ago.

You've got far more details in your question that what appears in the issue - you should add a note to the issue pointing here!

Comment: What exactly does *triaged* mean? I've been Googling it, can't find anything... in any case, this is kind of annoying but not the worst thing in the world. I surrounded the delete statement with a `try-catch-finally` to catch the error. Luckily, that error popping up actually signifies that event was manually deleted, meaning I can send out emails if I want to :D I also starred the issue and posted a comment with the link back to this question.

Comment: That's about all you could do, Chris. You could also delete your own copy of the event ID. Hmm... I wonder how many events are still floating around in the ether? AFAICT, when they mark an issue *triaged*, it means that a member of the team has looked at, assigned internal priority to it (not HIGH priority, apparently), and that it can now sit and wait. Kind of like an emergency room.

Comment: Haha, an "emergency" room nice ;) well, in any case I think I have around oh... several hundred *zombie* events just floating around my calendar, waiting to be dug up :P Now another interesting test... what happens if you try to delete a **calendar**?? Will the calendar ID still allow changes to be made to that calendar? Even **more** interesting of a test to do is to try to access a *deleted event inside a deleted calendar*! Like ***event-ception*** (if you get the reference) :P One of these days I'll get around to testing those scenarios :)